# Dynamic block size for ls command

Tags: linux, ls

Counting digits in the file sizes output by ls -l is not fun

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bear bear 1062608896 Feb 17 19:47 Stocks.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 bear bear         16 Feb 17 20:06 word
```

However, the alternative, using --block-size=MB yields deceptively large file sizes for small files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bear bear 1063MB Feb 17 19:47 Stocks.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 bear bear    1MB Feb 17 20:06 word
```

How can I get output that is both easy to read and not deceptive large for small files? If ls cannot do it, is there a convenient command-line alternative to ls that can do this?

For example, a desired output could be

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bear bear 1.04GB Feb 17 19:47 Stocks.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 bear bear    16B Feb 17 20:06 word
```

Comment: Is `ls -lh` not what you want?

Comment: O.O - I would downvote my own post if I could. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `ls(1)`:

> ```
>    -h, --human-readable
>           with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
>
>    --si   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024
> ```

Comment: Perfect Answer.